# File rendering for PDF file print

Tags: java, pdf

I tried below code for print the PDF file for

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    FileInputStream psStream = null;
    try {
        psStream = new FileInputStream("E://ssc exam.pdf");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ffne) {
          ffne.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (psStream == null) {
            return;
        }
    DocFlavor psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(psStream, psInFormat, null);  
    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(psInFormat, aset);

    // this step is necessary because I have several printers configured
    PrintService myPrinter = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++){
         String svcName = services[i].toString();   
        System.out.println("service found: "+svcName);

        if (svcName.contains("sfg")){
            myPrinter = services[i];
            System.out.println("my printer found: "+svcName);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (myPrinter != null) {            
        DocPrintJob job = myPrinter.createPrintJob();
        try {
        job.print(myDoc, aset);

        } catch (Exception pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();}
    } else {
        System.out.println("no printer services found");
    }
 }
}
```

but i got "PDF file not printed.128 MB of memory is required to enable direct PDF printing" error,So I decide to use PDF rendering for print the PDF.can anyone to help how to use PDFfile rendering concept in detail.

Comment: You might want to add some details, like: which library/component are you using. And just wondering: if the error tells you to go for more memory; did you try that - like starting the JVM with more heap memory?

Comment: might this example useful http://bigdatazone.blogspot.in/2012/09/pdf-printing-in-java.html